# Visio VBA - ReplaceShape throws Invalid Parameter

Tags: vba, visio

I've an issue which may be a bug, in Visio 2013 VBA.
I am trying to replace a shape in a master using VBA and the shape.ReplaceShape() command.

The strange thing is - if I call the sub on a shape/selection in my document page, it does replace the shape, however when I run it on a shape/selection in a master that is open for edit - it throws an invalid parameter message box error.

What I am trying to do is:
I have a stencil (not the document stencil) where I have a number of masters. Some of the more complex masters are made from including other masters - so basically a hierarchy of shapes. The issue is, if I edit a lower-level shape, my higher level shapes do not get the updates - meaning I have to propagate changes up manually - which is a pain. 
I turned to VBA to automate this, but have fallen afoul of this strange quirk in replaceShape not appearing to work for a master.

Any help on either how to allow replaceshape to work, or better still an alternative way to allow masters to be composed of others and have all changes reflected when any level is edited - would be greatly appreciated!

```
Example Code:
' replace a shape within a master with a fresh copy from the stencil
Public Sub stackoverflow_example()

Dim mst As Visio.Master
Dim mstCopy As Visio.Master ' an object to hold a copy of mst...

Dim target As String
Dim source As String

mst_name = "test"
target = "Adder.144"
source = "Adder"

Set mst = Visio.Documents("Schematic.vssx").Masters(mst_name)
Set rep = Visio.Documents("Schematic.vssx").Masters(source)

Debug.Print mst
Set mstCopy = mst.Open

Dim shp As Visio.Shape
Dim all_s As Visio.Shapes
Set all_s = mstCopy.Shapes

intShapeCount = all_s.Count

For intCounter = 1 To intShapeCount
   Set shp = all_s.Item(intCounter)
   If shp.name = target Then
      shp.ReplaceShape (rep)
   End If
Next intCounter

' save and clean up
mstCopy.Close
Set mstCopy = Nothing
Set mst = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Some code sample, please